# Why is my Powershell regex '?' quantifier not working as expected for entire capture group

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a Powershell regex that stops working when I add the '?' quantifier to the entire capture group.

The regex with the '?' quantifier at the end of my entire capture group does not return the expected result. In this case the result I expected was the same as without the quantifier.

```
$rec = " latest handshake: 128 days, 2 hours, 50 minutes, 33 seconds ago"
$rec -match "((?<Days>\d+)\sdays?(,\s+))?";
True
Matches;

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0
```

Without the last '?' shows that the capture group is parsed as expected.

```
$rec = " latest handshake: 128 days, 2 hours, 50 minutes, 33 seconds ago"
$rec -match "((?<Days>\d+)\sdays?(,\s+))";
True
$Matches;

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Days                           132
2                              ,
1                              132 days,
0                              132 days,
```

The following snippet shows using the quantifier at the end is valid.

```
"abc" -match "((abc)d?)?"
True
$Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              abc
1                              abc
0                              abc
```

First, I'm new so let me know if there is a better way to respond to comments than to revise the question.

Sorry I left out the $rec string assignment. The source is from a WireGuard server report. The goal of my script is to compute the last handshake in minutes. I was going to create an optional capture group for days?, hours?, minutes?, and seconds? and then calculate the minutes based on the present captures.

Possible $rec strings:

- latest handshake: 128 days, 2 hours, 50 minutes, 33 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 1 day, 2 hours, 50 minutes, 33 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 4 hours, 21 minutes, 48 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 1 hour, 45 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 1 hour, 1 minute, 22 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 2 minutes, 1 second ago
- latest handshake: 2 minutes ago
- latest handshake: 2 seconds ago
- latest handshake: 1 second ago
- latest handshake: Now

The last snippet (repeated below with a named capture group) was to show that adding the quantifier for capture group returns the same result as without it. I must be doing something incorrect that the the additional quantifier is not working with the original $rec.

```
#Without last quantifier #Without last quantifier
"abc" -match "(?<cap>()(abc)d?)"
True
Stats> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
cap                            abc
2                              abc
1
0                              abc


#With last quantifier
"abc" -match "(?<cap>(abc)d?)?"
True
Stats> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
cap                            abc
1                              abc
0                              abc
```

Comment: That last `?` makes everything optional, so the whole regex matches all empty strings between characters first and foremost, which accidentally prevents later attempts from matching the phrase since later matches cannot overlap previous ones.

Comment: What *exactly* is your original input (i.e. `$rec`), to every whitespace?

Comment: As you can see, `?` is working as expected. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The last snippet shows that it works as expected _when you pick the right input_. Try `" abc" -match "((abc)d?)?"` instead

Comment: Why would you want to make your entire match pattern optional?

Comment: I don't know if regex is the best option for finding the *largest* value among many inputs, but it can definitely help with parsing the syntax of each one

Comment: @Mark - I'm not trying to find the largest. The line could have any one or more time units. I was going to calculate total minutes with (days * 1440) + (hours * 60) + (minutes) + (seconds / 60) for the values present.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very well-known: if all your pattern matches an empty string, and you use it in a regex method that searches for a match just once, and the expected match happens to be located somewhere in the middle of the string, the regex engine "finds" the empty string at the start of the input string and returns it as a valid match.

You seem to want to parse the time period with a single regex that is used in a search-once `-match` regex method.

You can use a regex that looks for the digits before known words anywhere inside the string:

```
> $rx = '^(?=.*?(?<Days>\d+)\s*days?\b)?(?=.*?(?<Hours>\d+)\s*h(?:ou)?rs?\b)?(?=.*?(?<Minutes>\d+)\s*min(?:utes?)?\b)?(?=.*?(?<Seconds>\d+)\s*sec(?:ond)?s?\b)?(?=.*?(?<Now>\bNow\b))?'
> $rec = " latest handshake: 128 days, 2 hours, 50 minutes, 33 seconds ago"
> $rec -match $rx | Out-Null
> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Hours                          2
Days                           128
Minutes                        50
Seconds                        33
0
```

Then, you can handle the group numbers as you need.

**NOTE**: *this regex is only good for your strings where the string is known to contain only one **valid** time period*.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xESZ3t/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*?(?<Days>\d+)\s*days?\b)?` - an optional positive lookahead that will match the current location if it is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible, and then one or more digits (captured into `Days` named capturing group) and then zero or more whitespaces and then `day`, an optional `s` followed with a word boundary
- `(?=.*?(?<Hours>\d+)\s*h(?:ou)?rs?\b)?` - an optional positive lookahead that will match the current location if it is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible, and then one or more digits (captured into `Hours` named capturing group) and then zero or more whitespaces and then `hour` or `hr`, then an optional `s` followed with a word boundary
- `(?=.*?(?<Minutes>\d+)\s*min(?:utes?)?\b)?` - an optional positive lookahead that will match the current location if it is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible, and then one or more digits (captured into `Minutes` named capturing group) and then zero or more whitespaces and then `min` or `minute`, then an optional `s` followed with a word boundary
- `(?=.*?(?<Seconds>\d+)\s*sec(?:ond)?s?\b)?` - an optional positive lookahead that will match the current location if it is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible, and then one or more digits (captured into `Seconds` named capturing group) and then zero or more whitespaces and then `sec` or `second`, then an optional `s` followed with a word boundary
- `(?=.*?(?<Now>\bNow\b))?` - an optional positive lookahead that will match the current location if it is immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than newline char as few as possible, and then a `Now` string (captured into `Now` named capturing group) followed with a word boundary.